# Half a heart on a map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know how to modify my world folder (I think it's in here) so the player/players will only have half a heart. I'm aware you can't just erase the rest with command blocks. You might be able to with editing the world folder. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use commands blocks to put poison on everyone for the right amount of time `/effect (player) 19 1 (correct time)` and make a set of command blocks to check if the person has already joined before. You will also need to make sure the difficulty is **not** on peaceful, and you **can't** get food.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give (player) minecraft:poison 1 (correct time)`